# Creating Custom Code Syntax Highlighting Color Themes

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, color-theme

I've come across a couple of websites that have been very helpful in allowing people to create custom color themes for their favorite IDE's.

- [Visual Studio themes](http://studiostyl.es/)
- [Eclipse themes](http://www.eclipsecolorthemes.org)

Is there a similar website for *Vim*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about the Visual Studio and Eclipse themes you linked to, but I usually go to

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=625

for `vim` colorschemes. I think we can only talk about color **schemes** in `vim`

There's a *downloadable* collection of colorschemes, which may not be what you're looking for, but I suspect there must be some documentation on the vim.org website *somewhere* about creating your own colorscheme